# Two pipeline running when get failed

Tags: gitlab

i have written workflow rules as give below. it working fine but as soon as pipeline fails two failed pipelines run: one for merge and one for branch.
as well as i am also trying to run pipeline for a branch only when it is tag (which is not mentioned below).i am using CI_COMMIT_TAG but still its not working.
NOTE: I am using fast-forward merge for merge request

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $FORCE == "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^.*-stable$/
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      #when: never 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Comment: What do you mean by `when get failed` or `as soon as pipeline fails two failed pipelines run` -- pipeline failures do not trigger new pipelines.

Comment: @sytech  whenever there is some configuration mistake in .gitlab-ci.yml file and i push it to remote , pipeline fails , but two pipeline failed appears in gitlab ci-cd job board

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [`workflow:rules` Examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#workflow-rules-examples):

> [A]ll of the rules can be `when: never`, with a final `when: always` rule. Pipelines that match the `when: never` rules do not run. All other pipeline types run. For example:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - when: always
```

If you want to exclude certain conditions from triggering a pipeline, simply add more conditions with `when: never`. Explicitly stating when the pipeline should be run isn't necessary due to the final `when: always` condition. I believe you have multiple passing conditions causing multiple pipelines to be created.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $FORCE == "true" # <- remove this line
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^.*-stable$/
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      #when: never # <- uncomment or delete rule
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"' # <- unnecessary single quotes
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Comment: i did all this and i am trying more combination in workflow but was enable to remove detached pipeline when it getting failed

Comment: Is your project set up for branch pipelines or merge request pipelines?

Comment: merge request pipeline